# apt-get update: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: apt, updates

I do get the following error message(s) when running `apt-get update`:

> Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
>   503  Service Unavailable

The server is not behing a proxy, but there is a firewall, I suspect that the firewall is causing me troubles (transparant proxy?).

What kind of checks can I perform to be sure it is the firewall and not something else?
Which specific ports should I check in which way to get conclusive evidence?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your "Software Sources" ( I do not know which "buntu" you are using). Try a different server either in your country or in a nearby country. It works for me, when I occasionally get this problem.

Good Luck

Mal